# Convert POST to JSON

Tags: json, vb.net

I trying send information to server this works well but I need convert this POST to JSON.
How can I do it please?
thank you

```
Dim xPoslatUmo As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("UMOPoslat")
               If xPoslatUmo = "Ano" Then
                   Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("UMOServer"))
                   request.Method = "POST"
                   Dim postdata As String = "{""GENCELEK"":""SAS_CALLC""},{""GENMSGTEXT"":""info""},{""Volat"":" + xvolat + "},{""Stav"":""" + xstav + "},{""Info"":""" + Left(xinfo, 255) + "}"
                   Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata)
                   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                   request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
                   Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
                   dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
                   dataStream.Close()
                   Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
                   mlog.LogujKontroly(postdata)
                   mlog.LogujKontroly("Poslani UMO " + (CType(response, HttpWebResponse)).StatusDescription)
                   response.Close()
               Else
                   mlog.LogujKontroly("Poslani UMO  - je nastaveno neposilat")
               End If
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain your requirements.  You don’t really convert a Post to Json so much.  Post is really a method and json is a data format you would either pass to or receive from a method (like a post method). Are you looking to do something with the response from the above post method request?

Comment: Incidentally, the code appears to be missing a few `""` for the variable `postdata`.

Comment: Now looks post data: {"timestamp":"20220525","tags":["_jsonparsefailure"],"message":"{\"Volat\":Volat},{\"Stav\":\"KO},{\"Info\":\" Kampan: out_prodej_lead_pad_vypis_poplatku je ve stavu Activated}","headers":{"http_host":"12.34.56.78:9000","request_path":"/","connection":"Keep-Alive","http_user_agent":null,"http_accept":null,"content_length":"104","http_version":"HTTP/1.1","content_type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","request_method":"POST"},"host":"12.34.56.78","@timestamp":"2022-05-25T19:02:43.723Z"} . I think that a problem is here: tags":["_jsonparsefailure"]